# Flex 3.0 Drag and Drop

Tags: flex3, drag-and-drop

I have encountered a problem in a Flex application.

I have implemented drag and drop support from a List to a Canvas, and I DragManagers doDrag() - with.a proxy-image. In my custom DragDrop event handler, i place a new item on the Canvas. I use the event.localX/localY to position the new item.

It is working ok, but the problem is that I want the "new" image to appear exactly where the proxy-image is when i release the mouse button (x/y -wise).

Can I somehow get the proxys X,Y location. I thought that DragManager would have a reference to it but I can´t find it.

Thanks

/C

Answer (score 0):

Even though I save a ref to the proxy-object, it´s values are reset (naturally) in the drag-drop method.

I have found the answer by using the event.localX/Y variables.